# Does Visual Studio have a begin selection/set mark command like Emacs?

Tags: visual-studio

In Emacs, one can begin a selection (more accurately "set the mark") by pressing Ctrl-Space. Then, one can navigate around the file, e.g. by pressing End to go to the end of the current line, and the selection will follow the caret.
There is more to the Emacs mark than that, but my question is:

**Does Visual Studio 2013 have a way to begin a selection at the caret and have the selection follow the caret until ESC is pressed, or something similar?** Visual Studio has a command called "Edit.EmacsSetMark", but it does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I only know of SHIFT + cursor keys (including PgUp/PgDn, Home/End, and most of them also with Ctrl). Could take a bit of practice in your case, but very convenient IMO. The selection is cleared as soon as you use a cursor key with SHIFT released.

Even rectangular selections are supported if you also press ALT.

Then there is also the mouse of course. With variations by using SHIFT (extend selection) and ALT (rectangular).

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of for 2013, but you could do it in 2010 with this...[a link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09dc58c4-6f47-413a-9176-742be7463f92)